# How to update related entries of different tables when using Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there any shorter way to do this update?

```
void Update(Table1 table1Entry, Table2[] table2entries)
{
    entities.Table1.Attach(table1Entry);
    var table2EntriesIds = table2entries.Select(a => a.Id);
    var updates = entities.Table2
        .Where(a => table2EntriesIds.Contains(a.Id));
    foreach(var update in updates)
    {
        entities.Table2.Attach(update);
    }

    var deletions = entities.Table2
        .Where(a => a.Table1Id == table1Entry.Id);
        .Where(a => !table2EntriesIds.Contains(a.Id));
    foreach(var deletion in deletions)
    {
        entities.DeleteObject(deletion);
    }

    var insertions = table2entries.Except(matches);
    foreach(var insertion in insertions)
    {
        entities.AddToTable2(insertion);
    }

    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

where Table2 has an Table1_Id foreign key.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka no, it may have an error or two, but when correct it will still be very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct. You can optimize it so for example you will not load separately relations to update and relations to delete but you will still have to manually synchronize current detached state of your entities with state in the database. The only way to synchronize the state of the entity graph is to do it manually per entity and relation.

The question is if your code works. I think it doesn't. It doesn't update any records because it doesn't change state of the records to modified. You also cannot attach again record loaded from the context. As the last point if those table1 and table2 are somehow related I don't see any code working with the relation itself (unless you use FK properties).